# Use Powershell to connect to LDAP

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use Powershell to perform the following tasks?

1. My authenticate with my DN and password AND...
2. Search for a member of a group by email and show if it exists
3. List all members of a group and their properties?

EDIT:

I have the script below, but it just returns the DN of each user, but I need it to list all the user's properties, like mail.

```
Get-ADObject -SearchBase $BaseDN -Filter * -Properties member | Select-Object -ExpandProperty member
```

Comment: Active Directory or just generic LDAP? There are built-in interfaces for the former but some of them won't work for the latter.

Comment: It would be Active Directory. But the use of Powershell would be to validate some filters as originally we are trying to use PHP to connect but they never return the desired results.

Comment: Active Diretory - 2008 R2

Comment: If you cannot get RSAT installed on your machine and use the `built-in` PowerShell cmdlets that come with that to query AD, try playing with `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` but might need to copy over some files before it'll import here's a snippet of a few variations I've used this solution before but adjustments will be needed to fulfill what you are after more precisely: https://i.imgur.com/eILKCK5.png. Maybe this will give you (or others) some ideas to test with and do some googling on. In a time crunch at the moment or I'd help more otherwise.